# Set \currenttime to specifc date and time

Tags: datetime, build-system

So I know this question may come across a bit weird but I'm looking for a way to change what LaTeX considers the current time. (In other words what `\currenttime` is for LaTeX)

I'd like to have this for easily reproducible builds of LaTeX documents. I do get the correct timestamp from somewhere externally.

So I cannot permanently change the tex file itself. In the (git) repository it must remain as `\currenttime`.

I came up with a number of possible solutions but they all seem a bit hacky to me and so I am wondering if there's a better way to do it.
These possible solutions are:

- Set the date and time of the build machine.
  I'm going to use Docker anyways so I could just set the time of the build container. Though that might mess with some stuff so I'm not too keen on doing that.
- Use something like `sed` to replace `\currenttime` with the desired timestamp.
  I currently don't know what format such a timestamp needs to be in I'm sure that's trivial to google. Also I don't like that this alters the tex file itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recent pdfTeX, etc., recognise two environmental variables here:

- `SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH` - Unix epoch value
- `FORCE_SOURCE_DATE` - switch to enable use of the epoch (set to 1 or higher)

So if you set them in the environment, pdfTeX, etc., will always 'see' the same date and time.

Comment: Does lualatex accept these too? Or is there an alternative for lualatex?

Comment: The answer to that is yes. I also misread the answer (glossed over the ", etc." part).